# Datatables extermal paging - Clone just one Button

Tags: jquery, button, datatables, paging

I am using jQuery/PHP datatables and I want to move or clone a single pagination button (the last page button only) to a div outside the Table.

I tried this one but I wasn't able to get just the "last" Button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#example").dataTable();
  $("#mynewdiv").append($(".dataTables_paginate"));
} );
```

I also tried these

```
$("#mynewdiv").append($(".last.paginate_button"));
$("#mynewdiv").append($(".dataTables_paginate.last"));
```

Is it possible to do something like that ?

Comment: I think, you should be using [`clone function`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) and if you want to remove button from pagination of datatable and display it only in your div then use [`detach`](https://api.jquery.com/detach/)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution for my problem.
So for everyone who has the same problem, heres a possible solution.

**The Javascript Part**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    $('#lastpage').on('click', function () {
        table.page('last').draw(false);
    });

});

</script>
```

**A simple button**

```
<button id="lastpage" type="button">Go to the last page</button>
```